# tagsinput is not a function

Tags: jquery, reactjs, bootstrap-tags-input

I am trying to use bootstrap-tagsinput in my react application. I have include bootstrap-tags input script in my index.jade file. I am getting an error saying

```
AddTagSection.js:102 Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _jquery2.default)(...).tagsinput is not a function
```

This is my index.jade file

```
extends layout


block head_scripts

        script(src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js')
        script(src='/public/ion.rangeSlider.js')
        link(href='/public/normalize.css' rel="stylesheet")
        link(href='/public/ion.rangeSlider.css' rel="stylesheet")
        link(href='/public/ion.rangeSlider.skinFlat.css' rel='stylesheet')
        script(src="/public/bootstrap-tagsinput.js")
        link(href="/public/bootstrap-tagsinput.css")
```

My code line also doesn't highlight tagsinput().

He is my code. I want to show that ionRangeSlider plugin is working but tagsinput is not working (giving the error mentioned above).[image: React is not even suggesting or highlighting tagsinput() yellow, like ionRangeSlider]

```
    componentDidMount = () => {
            $(this.slider_el).ionRangeSlider();
            this.slider = $(this.slider_el).data('ionRangeSlider')
             $(this.tag_input_el).tagsinput()

        }



 <div className="irs-wrapper">
                            <input
                                ref={node => this.slider_el = node}
                                type="text"
                                id="ionSlider-newTag"
                                name="ionSlider"
                                value="0;2057"/>
                        </div>
                        <br/>
                        <div className="form-group form-group-default">
                            <label>Tags</label>
                            <input ref={node => this.tag_input_el = node}
                                   id="tagsinput"
                                   type="text"
                                   value="Smoking,Drinking"
                                   data-role="tagsinput"/>
                        </div>
```

Comment: Please add your code for script includes of jquery, ionRangeSlider and tagsInput to your original post.

Comment: Done. Check update.

Comment: Could you try importing the bootstrap.js file contained in the bootstrap package before the tagsInput please?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. Why do i need to import it when I have included it in script?

Comment: You are importing `bootstrap-tagsinput.js`, I want you to import `bootstrap.js` before that due to possible dependencies on that package.

Comment: Tried. Still the same error.

Comment: @ApurvG any progress? i'm facing the same error